# How to check if any tuple same as previsious or next

Tags: python

I have a two lists

```
list1=[(1, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2)]    
list2=[(1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2)]
```

How to check If any tuple is a same as next one or previous, but the tuple with index 0 can be the same as last tuple:

in `list1` must return `False`, because [(1, 3), **(1, 2)**, (2, 2), **(1, 2)**]

in `list2` must return True, because the last element is the same as first [**(1, 2)**, (1, 1), (2, 2), **(1, 2)**]

---

But if `L=[(2, 2), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3)]` it return False, why?                                                                             Must return True

Comment: Have you produced any code so far?

Comment: I don't have idea how to write that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> list1=[(1, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2)]
>>> list2=[(1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2)]
>>> any(x == y for x, y in zip(list1[-1:]+list1, list1))
False
>>> any(x == y for x, y in zip(list2[-1:]+list2, list2))
True
```

Always be careful when you are adding lists together, although this is rare, in some cases your lists will be very huge and you dont want to create another huge list in memory. In this case you can use `itertools.chain` and also `itertools.izip` which are iterators, and both save making a list in memory. In Python 3 `zip` behaves like `izip`

```
>>> from itertools import chain, izip
>>> any(x == y for x, y in izip(chain([list2[-1]], list2), list2))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def check(L):
    i = 0
    while i < len(L)-1:
        if L[i] == L[(i-1)%len(L)] or L[i] == L[(i+1)%len(L)]:
            return True
        i += 1
    return False
```

Output:

```
In [235]: check([(1, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2)])
Out[235]: False

In [236]: check([(1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2)])
Out[236]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is just a little bit less tricky.

```
    def check(L):
        if L[0] == L[-1]:
            return True
        for i in range(len(L)-1):
            if L[i] == L[i+1]:
                return True
        return False

    print check([(1, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2)])
    print check([(1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2)])
```